# Prerequisites for Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis

Hello I am a sophomore and I would like to know if Michael's other book named 'Calculus' is enough preparation for the Manifolds, if not please do tell what else should I be reading? I am taking an introductory course to topology next semester as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You also need to know some linear algebra.

Answer (score 5):

You also need some topology, one semester is probably enough, and you need linear algebra. The linear algebra needs to be oriented to the theory of vector spaces and linear maps without always studying things in terms of bases and matrices. Linear algebra courses in applied math, engineering, statistics, etc. will likely not be sufficient. I recommend Hoffman and Kunze.

Multivariate calculus (e.g. Stewart) is helpful but not necessary. It's often taught as Calculus 3 in a typical sequence. I recommend it because theoretical texts, like the Spivak you are referring to, often deemphasize computation to the point that you forget that being able to calculate integrals and volumes is a big part of why we study this at all. If you use Stewart, you should note that the chapters on path integrals are actually about manifolds and are much harder than the rest of the book.

I'll also note that none of my professors thought there was really any good book on manifolds, which is a topic somewhere between real analysis and differential geometry, and arguably algebraic geometry (in terms of mathematical maturity). You might cross-learn from Munkres, or try to find open courseware notes or lectures on the topic, e.g. MIT or Stanford.

Comment: does Munkres's book require linear algebra too?

Comment: @OmarQasem yes.

Comment: Is it 'ok' to study the vector spaces and linear transformations from paul dawkins notes? or do I need to study the book you mentioned?

Comment: Two remarks: the formal prerequisites for Spivak do not state topology is required, and formal prerequisites for Munkres do not state linear algebra is required.

Comment: well I am taking topology either way, my problem is that I don't like the subject of linear algebra much.

Comment: @OmarQasem it's fundamental to **all math, science, and engineering**. Find something you enjoy about it. It's not like chocolate or vanilla ice cream, you don't get farther in life by knowing which you like and don't like.

Comment: @djechlin http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-700-linear-algebra-fall-2013/readings/ this is a sufficient theory based linear algebra course at MIT I just hope you can tell me what topics of the reading material matters as a prerequisite for analysis on manifolds? so far all you said is vector spaces and linear maps but perhaps there are others? thank you

Comment: @OmarQasem can't recall. Ideally learn all of it.

Comment: @OmarQasem btw you shouldn't accept my answer yet. it's easy to get other answers when the question is still open and this is a soft enough question it will benefit from other answers. give it a few days or maybe a week before accepting.

Comment: @OmarQasem and I think you need the material *and* the mathematical maturity from a linear algebra course. you can skip as much as you want but that's all the better chance you won't get anything out of calculus/analysis on manifolds and won't even realize you're not getting anything out of it. I'm not a strong believer in self-study -- I personally couldn't tackle either of those courses without the support of a course or at least a peer group. But I'd still tilt to learning linear algebra with some vigor.

Comment: @djechlin thank you once more, I removed the acceptance for now.